# Why is `.onAppear` called twice when view is inside TabView

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to load a remote resource, so I'm using `.onAppear` to do that. However, when I use `if/else` inside the view, it causes the it to fire twice.

```
class FooVM: ObservableObject {
   @Published var remoteText: String? = nil

   func load() {
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
         self.remoteText = "\(Date())"
      }
   }
}

struct Foo: View {

   @StateObject private var vm = FooVM()

   var body: some View {
      content
         .onAppear(perform: vm.load)
   }

   @ViewBuilder
   private var content: some View {
      if let text = vm.remoteText {
         Text(text)
      } else {
         Circle()
      }
   }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Foo()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    Text("Home")
                } 
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: Turns out it only repro's when the content is inside a `TabView`. I updated the code above**

Why is `onAppear` (and thus `load`) firing twice? <sub>Actually, in the Playground, it fires repeatedly every 2 seconds, but in a simulator in fires only twice.</sub>

How do I avoid it? Bear in mind that this is a simplified example.

---

Interestingly, if it wasn't a choice between `Text` and `Circle`, but just a different text within `Text`, then it would fire only once:

```
Text(vm.remoteText ?? "loading...")
```

Comment: With Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1 `load` is called only once with provided code. Which env did you use?

Comment: Xcode 12.2 / iOS 14.2

Comment: I'm on 12.2 / iOS 14.2 and only see load called once as well. Have you tried on a simulator / outside of Playground?

Comment: @nicksarno, yes - trying it on a simulator actually

Comment: Well I cant reproduce it with the current code. The only thing that comes to mind is maybe the view would 'reappear'  when the content switches. Try embedding 'content' in a ZStack and calling .onAppear on the ZStack instead. This way the ZStack remains while the content re-appears? Just guessing here haha

Comment: @Asperi, turns out I oversimplified my example. I can now repro it when it's within `TabView`. Can you take a look again?

Comment: @nicksarno, I tried it in a clean environment, and indeed it didn't fire twice. So, I realized that it's the addition of `TabView` that causes it... Updated the question.

Comment: This is not ideal but you can try using `init` in `Foo`. It should be called once only.

Comment: @NewDev I believe my comment above is still the solution. I will add an answer below for you to check.

Comment: @pawello2222, I tried that, but that didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your content is switching within the if statement, Foo() has to completely re-appear. The solution is to embed the content of Foo() within a ZStack (or similar) so that it doesn't need to re-appear the entire view and call .onAppear again. Here, the ZStack remains appeared while the content switches.

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content
        }
        .onAppear(perform: vm.load)
   }
```

Comment: Indeed using `VStack` or `ZStack` (but not `Group`) solves this. Thanks! I don't think, though, the reason you provided - i.e. `Foo` needs to re-render - is correct, since `Foo` doesn't need to re-render when not inside a `TabView`. Also, why `VStack`/`ZStack` removes the need to re-render, but not `_ConditionalContent<Text, Circle>` (which is what `content` is). If you could amend the explanation, i'll accept this as an answer. Thanks

Comment: I guess re-render was the wrong word. It seems like it has more to do with the .onAppear placement than the TabView. If you have a full explanation for this, feel free to add your own answer above mine.

Comment: Thanks @nicksarno for your solution it helped me. 
Just adding a small note as someone might face my issue, when I added embedded my content inside ZStack it had a large space on the top thus I added (alignment: .top) to the ZStack.